# Passing json to EJS

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, get, ejs

I'm trying to pass data from my database to the client(EJS template). 
However, the data isn't outputting, and I'm not getting any errors doing so.
So I tried to console.log the data to my terminal and it does show, it just does not show up on the ejs page.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- LOCAL INFORMATION -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well">
            <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Local</h3>

            <p>
                <strong>id</strong>: <%= user._id %><br>
                <strong>email</strong>: <%= user.local.username %><br>
                <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.local.password %><br />
                <strong>text</strong>: <%= text %>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the backend:

```
  app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    var text;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/manage", (err, db) => {
      db.collection("data", (err, collection) => {
        collection.find().toArray((err, res) => {
          if(err){
            throw err;
          }
          text = res[0].string;
          console.log(text);
        });
      });
    });
    res.render('auth/profile', {
      user: req.user,
      text: text
    });
  });
```

Notice that there's a `console.log(text)` , and that does output the correct text to the terminal, I'm just having issues passing it through to the client. All the user's data outputs correctly as well.

Comment: have you tried to output the variables without spaces? `<%=user.local.username%>`

Comment: @turmuka all the user ones work, only the text fails to output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your `res.render` within the callback of your query, for example:

```
 app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    var text;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/manage", (err, db) => {
      db.collection("data", (err, collection) => {
        collection.find().toArray((err, response) => {
          if(err){
            throw err;
          }
          text = response[0].string;
          console.log(text);
          res.render('auth/profile', {
           user: req.user,
           text: text
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

The way you have it setup now it's being executed before the callback is finished and its out of scope.  Also, you generally don't want to put your database connection inside your routes.  You would want to do one database connection when your node server starts, then pass that connection to your routes to re-use the connection, otherwise every time your route is hit, you're re-connecting to the db.

To add, you also wouldn't want to do `throw err` as this will stop your node process (I assume you're using express?).  Instead just log the error or do a return and `res.render` and include the error so you can handle it in your view.

Edit:

In your callback for `toArray` you have to change the name of the response from `res` to `response` or anything other than `res`, so you don't override the server `res` object.

Comment: Noted about the error, but I get the error of "res.render is not a function" if I place it inside the toArrays function

Comment: Also I'd like to note, since user's data displays correctly, I don't think it's the position of res.render that's causing the problem

Comment: @JustinLi I've updated the code example and an explanation.  It's 100% the position of the `res.render` - remember, node is asynchronous, if you want data that comes from a callback (i.e., database query) you have to be within that callback.   Also, as noted, make sure you don't use `res` as that will override your server `res` variable.

Comment: @JustinLi To explain further, it looks you have `isLoggedIn` middleware.  This gets called prior to even hitting your route.  Assuming that is what's populating `res.user`, this is why res.user is available.